# Subselect in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I have the following table, representing buses and the points at which they stop.

```
bus_table

bus stop_no station_id 
  1       1          1 
  1       2          2
  1       3          3
  2       1          7
  2       2          8
  2       3          9
  3       1          3
  3       2          4
  3       3          5
  3       4          6
  3       5          7
```

I want to get from station 1 to station 9.

What query can I write for that?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM query_test WHERE stat IN 
(SELECT stat FROM query_test WHERE Name = 'b3');`

this :) @sagi

Comment: this actually works, but I got a feeling that its not the right way to do it:
`SELECT * FROM bus_table WHERE stat IN 
(SELECT stat FROM bus_table WHERE Name = 'b3') AND NAME NOT like 'b3';`

Comment: This is a graph traversal problem.  Many databases have support for hierarchical and recursive queries, so such a problem can be addressed using a single `select`.  MySQL is not one of those databases.  You would need to write a stored procedure.

Comment: @Strawberry I dont understand what you mean. Are you saying I need another column? what data would that column hold?

Comment: @Strawberry and than it would be possible? I can add that column, if that is what is needed

Comment: It would be possible, but see Gordon's comment above. MySQL doesn't natively support recursion, so you have to simulate it in some way. Gordon has (rather forcefully) suggested one method. But others are available.

Comment: @Strawberry I was going to write a little php script that will query the database and return the results. could it be possible that the php script helps out to get the results I need?

Comment: Yes. Include the PHP tag in your question.

Comment: @Strawberry sorry, I didn't add it because I thought it was irrelevant. I assumed it was a mysql question/solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By way of example. Obviously, this solution is not recursive - but you could just keep iterating through bus routes until you got from A to B.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bus_routes;


CREATE TABLE bus_routes 
(bus_no INT NOT NULL
,stop_no INT NOT NULL
,station_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(bus_no,stop_no)
);

INSERT INTO bus_routes VALUES
(1,1,1),
(1,2,2),
(1,3,3),
(2,1,7),
(2,2,8),
(2,3,9),
(3,1,3),
(3,2,4),
(3,3,5),
(3,4,6),
(3,5,7);

SELECT a_from.bus_no
     , a_from.station_id start_from
     , b_from.station_id first_change_at
     , b_from.bus_no to_bus
     , c_from.station_id then_change_at
     , c_from.bus_no to_bus
     , c_to.station_id alighting_at
  FROM bus_routes a_from  
  JOIN bus_routes a_to 
    ON a_to.bus_no = a_from.bus_no 
   AND a_to.stop_no > a_from.stop_no
  JOIN bus_routes b_from
    ON b_from.station_id = a_to.station_id
  JOIN bus_routes b_to
    ON b_to.bus_no = b_from.bus_no
   AND b_to.stop_no > b_from.stop_no
  JOIN bus_routes c_from
    ON c_from.station_id = b_to.station_id
  JOIN bus_routes c_to
    ON c_to.bus_no = c_from.bus_no
   AND c_to.stop_no > c_from.stop_no
 WHERE a_from.station_id = 1
   AND c_to.station_id = 9;

+--------+------------+-----------------+--------+----------------+--------+--------------+
| bus_no | start_from | first_change_at | to_bus | then_change_at | to_bus | alighting_at |
+--------+------------+-----------------+--------+----------------+--------+--------------+
|      1 |          1 |               3 |      3 |              7 |      2 |            9 |
+--------+------------+-----------------+--------+----------------+--------+--------------+
```

Comment: If the table would grow in number of busses, would the number of Joins also grow or just if the busses share stations? I'm not sure if this answer would work if the amount of busses would be unknown. (I didn't ask for this in my original question, thats why I accepted this answer, since it works)

Answer (score 0):

Recursive traversal of the graph of bus stops (tested on MSSQL 2016):

```
DECLARE @from NCHAR(4) = 'ort1';
DECLARE @to NCHAR(4) = 'ort9';

WITH [route] ([path], [lastBus], [current])
AS
    (SELECT CAST(N'' AS NVARCHAR(1000)) AS [path], CAST(N'' AS NCHAR(2)) AS [lastBus], @from AS [current]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST( cur.[path] + N',' + busesAvailable.name + N' to ' + [next].stat AS NVARCHAR(1000)) AS [path],
        busesAvailable.name AS [lastBus],
        [next].stat AS [current]
    FROM [route] cur
    INNER JOIN dbo.BusStat busesAvailable ON busesAvailable.stat = cur.[current] AND busesAvailable.name <> cur.[lastBus]
    INNER JOIN dbo.BusStat [next]
        ON [next].stat <> cur.[current]
        AND [next].name = busesAvailable.name)
SELECT TOP 1 [route].[path]
FROM [route]
WHERE [route].[current] = @to;
```

That considering the table is created with:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BusStat]
(
    [name] NCHAR (2) NOT NULL,
    [stat] NCHAR (4) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[BusStat] ([name], [stat])
SELECT 'b1',    'ort1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'b1',    'ort2' UNION ALL
SELECT 'b1',    'ort3' UNION ALL
SELECT 'b2',    'ort7' UNION ALL
SELECT 'b2',    'ort8' UNION ALL
SELECT 'b2',    'ort9' UNION ALL
SELECT 'b3',    'ort3' UNION ALL
SELECT 'b3',    'ort4' UNION ALL
SELECT 'b3',    'ort5' UNION ALL
SELECT 'b3',    'ort6' UNION ALL
SELECT 'b3',    'ort7';
```